# Recommended type to use in Metadata when Validating Model Data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, metadata

This is a minor question, more of a curiosity.  When creating MetaData class for Model Validation, what is the recommended variable type to use for each property.

In the MSDN example, they use *Object* for all properties

```
[MetadataType(typeof(ProductMD))]
public partial class Product {
    public class ProductMD {
        [StringLength(50),Required]
        public object Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Other examples online use the same type as the model:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(ProductMD))]
public partial class Product {
    public class ProductMD {
        [StringLength(50),Required]
        public String Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime ArrivalDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Does the property type matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type does not matter, that's why you can just use `Object`. Properties must match by name.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Is there an advantage to use Object or anything else? (speed, convention, etc..)?

Comment: @mcbros: I think using `Object` is a good convention that emphasizes the fact that the type of the property is not relevant. You also don't need to worry about types matching, in case they change.